# Spannable text shows only for a second, when button is clicked. Why?

Tags: java, android

I want to set a `spannable` string in my text view when a button is clicked, where the first word has white foreground color and striked out and the second word has red foreground color. This is my code:

**My textview:**

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/charge_per_month"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="16pt">
</TextView>
```

**My java code:**

```
TextView charge_month = findViewById(R.id.charge_per_month);

String exp_amount = "₹ 5600"; //should be white in color and striked out

String act_amount = "₹ 6708"; //should be red in color

String complete_string = exp_amount + "  "+act_amount;

submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onClick(View view) {

        Spannable str = new SpannableString (complete_string);

        str.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, exp_amount.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE),0, exp_amount.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),exp_amount.length() + 1,complete_string.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        charge_month.setText(str);
     
        }
}
```

The spannable string just shows for a split second, when the button is clicked. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 TextView charge_month = findViewById(R.id.charge_per_month);
    String exp_amount = "₹ 5600";
    String act_amount = "₹ 6708";
    String complete_string = exp_amount + "  " + act_amount;
    Spannable str = new SpannableString(complete_string);
    str.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, 6, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE),0, 6, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),6, str.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    charge_month.setText(str);
```

click this link to check out look like - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBCwf.jpg

Comment: Tried it, still not working.

Comment: @Labji thanks for the comment, now check the above code I update the answer

Answer (score 0):

change this from:

```
str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),exp_amount.indexOf(exp_amount.charAt(0)),act_amount.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

to

```
str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),exp_amount.length() + 1,complete_string.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```